# Change default port MYSQL on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I just install and setup remote server, and I have to change the default port.

Because by changing the `port` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cond.d`, I can't reload mysql after this change.

To know: my goal is to connect with mysqli_connect (PHP) on port 995, and not 3306.

Comment: What user are you running MySQL as? Might be useful to include portions of your config file and any logs you might have as well.

Comment: My ```/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf``` is configure as :

Comment: [mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
tmpdir          = /tmp
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
mysqlx-bind-address     = 0.0.0.0

Comment: And I'm using a user configured for all incoming address

Comment: You have to know that I can connect with mysqli_connect on port 3306 from my computer to my distant MYSQL server, but I want to do that by port 995

Comment: My problem if I understand well, is that I try to use port 995, but this is an already use port, because we have to use port > 1023

Comment: Yeah, lower ports tend to be reserved. I think a root user can use lower ports, but probably not a great idea as you discovered.